# Mounting Google Drive to Python Colab error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Someone uploaded a folder on Google Drive and shared it with me. I installed Google Colab and opened an IPhython notebook in colab. For connecting it with Google Drive, I did:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

I continued to run the code and do some imports, and at some point I need to give the path for this folder. I tried:

```
path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/the_folder/"
```

But when I checked on the left-hand-side, under `"Files"->"gdrive"->"MyDrive"`, it's not even there, so no wonder it's not found when I run the code later. Did I mount it incorrectly?

Comment: So what is the question? How to mount the drive?

Comment: I believe there must be an error in the way I mounted it since I don't find the folder under the files.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Are you inputting the confirmation string to confirm drive mounting? If yes then I have no idea, you could try to add `force_remount=True` as argument of `mount` function.

Comment: Is the path correct? As you are not an owner of the folder (it was only shared to you), you propably have to create a link of it (right-click on the folder) inside your Drive. In that way, this folder will "exist" in your Drive and not only in the "Available for me" tab.

Comment: @ans that must be the problem. I did get the link, but -silly question- how do I make the folder "appear" in my Drive? It's still only in "Available for me".

Comment: @futuredataengineer, right-click on this folder while in the "Shared with me" tab (I called it "Available for me") and then "Add shortcut to Drive" (you will have to choose the place on your Drive) to create a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to work with a **shared by someone** Google Drive folder (you are not an owner of which) in Google Colab, you should, first of all, create a shortcut of this folder inside your Drive, as it exists in the Drive of its owner.

It can be done following way: right-click on this folder while in the `Shared with me` tab of the Google Drive  and then click on the `Add shortcut to Drive`. This way *your* Drive will contain the folder (a shortcut), which was *created and shared by someone else*.

Then, after a regular mount procedure this folder will be accessible from Google Colab.